# Why does the read end of a pipe read EOF only if the write end is closed?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I don't really understand the difference between "closing the write end of the pipe" and "not writing anything to the pipe". If I don't write anything to the pipe and the pipe is empty, why is the read end simply blocked rather than reading an EOF? How is that different from closing the write end?

Comment: Well think of it like a telephon. Just because nobody is saying anything at the moment does not mean that they won't start soon. EOF is like them hanging up.

Comment: good answer to similar question applies partially to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499732/123739

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reading an EOF from a pipe (or from anything) indicates that there's no more input, and that there won't be any more input in the future.

If there's no input available at the moment, but the pipe hasn't been closed, then the reader will (by default) block waiting for input; if the writer then writes to the pipe, that data will become available to the reader. An EOF would tell the reader to stop trying to read any more data.

Comment: So EOF is not like a literal thing read from the pipe? It's like a signal that the kernel sends to the read end when all the write ends are closed?

Comment: @Xufeng: Correct. EOF is a made up value for the C library. It doesn't exist in the operating system.

Comment: @Xufeng: Right. It would be more accurate to call it an end-of-file condition. How it's indicated depends on how you read from the pipe. If you use `fgetc()`, it will return `EOF`, a negative `int` value that's distinct from any `unsigned char` value. Some other functions return the number of items read; for example, the `read()` function returns `0` to indicate end-of-file. (Or an error condition.)

Comment: +1: Note that terminals (tty and pty devices) can generate zero bytes to read multiple times while a file is open. At the Unix `read()` level, if you try reading again after getting zero bytes, you continue with the next data if there is any. At the standard I/O level, once you get EOF (or an error) from a file, you continue to get it until you reposition the stream (`fseek()` etc) or clear the error (`clearerr()`). Sample code in next comment. (Type lines of text at it; type control-D part way through a line, or at the beginning of a line; you need to generate 5 EOF messages before it exits.)

Comment: `#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { char buffer[4096]; int nbytes; int eof_count = 0; int read_count = 0; while (eof_count < 5) { while ((nbytes = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) printf("[%d:%d]<<%.*s>>\n", ++read_count, nbytes, nbytes, buffer); if (nbytes == 0) printf("EOF %d detected\n", ++eof_count); else if (nbytes < 0) { puts("Error detected - exiting"); break; } } puts("All done"); return 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

That's the protocol for the *blocking* file descriptors. The read end of the pipe *waits* for data. Closing the write end of it signals end-of-stream. That is actually a powerful synchronization concept.

You can switch the pipe to *non-blocking* mode, where lack of data is treated as soft error, so you can just check whether there's anything to read. This is very useful when you have more than one file descriptor to read from (like in a server handling multiple clients). That's where *IO multiplexing* comes in.