# C - How to detect EOF in pipe when reading only single char?

Tags: c, pipe, eof, file-descriptor

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210534/why-does-the-read-end-of-a-pipe-read-eof-only-if-the-write-end-is-closed) answer, I'd be expecting the **reader process** to catch the `EOF` right after the **writer process** closes all related file descriptors.

But that doesn't happen and this program ends up stuck in an endless loop.
Parent waits for it's child to finish & child waits for `EOF` signalizing closed pipe.

#### Why the reader process doesn't receive `EOF`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wait.h>

#define STRING_TO_SEND "Hello, world!\n"

int main() {
    int fd[2], i = 0;
    __pid_t pid;
    char _char;
    ssize_t nbytes;

    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        // Error
        perror("Error forking!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    } else if (pid == 0) {

        // Child
        close(fd[1]);
        while ((nbytes = read(fd[0], &_char, 1)) != EOF) {
            if (nbytes == 0)
                continue;
            putchar(_char);
        }
        close(fd[0]);

    } else {

        // Parent
        close(fd[0]);

        for(;;) {
            _char = STRING_TO_SEND[i++];
            write(fd[1], &_char, 1);
            if (_char == '\0')
                break;
        }

        close(fd[1]);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);

        while (wait(NULL)>0) {}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `read()` returns `0` when there's no more data to read, not `EOF` (which is guaranteed to be negative and is usually `-1`).  You only get `-1` from `read()` if there's an error; no more data is not an error.

Comment: Then why there is no `EOF`, when **writer process** closes it's `fd`?

Comment: There is an end-of-file condition, and the `read()` call is telling you that by returning `0`.  You're busy ignoring what it tells you, so it repeats itself, but your code isn't learning from what `read()` said, so the cycle goes on for a long time.

Comment: Oh, I see! The `read()` function starts reading after there are some data available! Thus `0` bytes read implies the `fd` was closed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I've thought that `read()` function returns `0` bytes even before there are any data sent ...

Comment: The `read()` system call blocks until there is data to read, or it can tell that there will never be any more data to read.  AFAICR, even if you set the `O_NONBLOCK` attribute on the file descriptor, `0` indicates EOF (you'd get `-1` and `errno == EAGAIN` if the non-blocking descriptor had no data available).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply misunderstood the "end of file" indication of `read()` which simply means nothing more to read for `read()` (read() returns 0 in that case). But `read()` doesn't actually return the *value* `EOF`. So your condition should be:

```
while ((nbytes = read(fd[0], &_char, 1)) > 0) {
```

Also `__pid_t` is an internal type of your C library. You shouldn't use that; just use `pid_t`.

See [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)'s man page for details.

Comment: I don't need the `nbytes` then :)

Comment: Yes, unless you are interested in differentiating "end of file" condition (when read() returns 0) with error condition (when read() returns -1).

Answer (score 1):

`EOF` is a constant usually defined to -1 that `stdio` (the C library buffering layer around the raw system calls) uses to signal end of file in functions like `getchar()` which conflate the returned character with an end-of-file signal.

`read` signals end-of-file by simply returning `0`. Note that it can also return -1 if there's an error (e.g., you can get `EINTR` if the read is interrupted by a signal handler before it read anything).

Consequently, what you want is something like:

```
while ((nbytes = read(fd[0], &_char, 1)) > 0){ /*...*/ }
if (0>nread) { /*report error (or maybe repeat if it's EINTR)*/ }
```

Manpages ([read(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read)) or the [POSIX spec for read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html) document all this.