# When reading a stream of input from stdin, how do we know that there's no input left?

Tags: c, file-io, pipe, posix, stdin

In particular, I'm writing an interpreter, and I'd like it to run source code from STDIN if no source file is given.

So I wrote a tiny program that is basically just a loop that, upon each iteration, reads a line from STDIN and adds it to a linked list, then prints the list when it's done. When I pipe a file to this program, i.e. `cat my_awesome_file | ./tiny_program`, it does in fact print the list and subsequently exit. How does it know to do this? Does cat send a `sigint` to `tiny_program`? Is there some sentinel byte (maybe the null byte) that conveys "hey, I'm done sending you stuff now"?

So in summary, my program is working fine, but I don't really know *why* it's working fine, and I'd very much like to.

Here's my tiny program, in rust. The exact code is probably not relevant, but maybe someone will find it helpful.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut ll: LinkedList<String> = LinkedList::new();
    for line in std::io::stdin().lines() {
        ll.push_back(line.unwrap());
    }
    println!("{:?}", ll);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code as well? Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Generally you read until EOF is reached.

Comment: When `cat` finishes outputting, it terminates and no longer adds input to the pipe. Your program drains the pipe as its input. When there's no more to be drawn out of the pipe, there's no more to be drawn out of the pipe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210534/why-does-the-read-end-of-a-pipe-read-eof-only-if-the-write-end-is-closed

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389373/how-can-pipe-producer-tell-pipe-consumer-it-has-reached-end-of-file-un-name

Comment: @GauravPathak There's nothing to reproduce really, so I don't think MCRE applies. I suppose I could post my code, but again, I'm asking a general question, so I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: These seems apropos:  [**Useless use of cat?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and [**Useless Use of Cat Award**](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Programs communicate with kernel.
- Kernel does all the transfer of bytes and keeps state
- Shell creates a `pipe()`.
- Shell `fork()` two processes as part of pipeline `cat` and `./tiny_program`.
- The processes have `dup2` the file descriptoes from `pipe()`.
- `cat` `write()`s to the pipe from one side.
- Kernel receives bytes from `write()`, saves them to a temporary storage.
- `./tiny_program` `read()`s from the pipe from the other side.
- Kernel sees if there are bytes in temporary storage and returns them.
- `cat` does `close()`
- Kernel sees that `close()` was done, and marks that the pipe is closed.
- `./tiny_program` does `read()`
- Kernel sees that there are no more bytes in temporary storage. Beacuse the pipe is closed, kernel returns `0`.
- Because `./tiny_program` is reading in blocking mode, `0` from `read()` means the stream is closed.
- `./tiny_program` terminates.

> Does cat send a sigint to tiny_program?

No.

> Is there some sentinel byte (maybe the null byte) that conveys "hey, I'm done sending you stuff now"?

No, there is a state in kernel memory that keeps track of the pipe state. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/pipe.c#L720